# How to provide an expression/function to a formatter/filter parameter in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for a way to display something like `{{model.tauxInteret|number:3}}`, with 3 being provided with another variable ie: `{{model.tauxInteret|number:model.precision}}`, or using a function `{{model.tauxInteret|number:myPrecisionFilter(model)}}` ....

Any idea if there is a way to do this in angluarJS (without moving the all thing on the controller part with a scope function like `{{displayTaux(model)}}` (which is my current workaround) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried your own suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//plook.injoin.io/angular/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module( "app", [] ).run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.pi = Math.PI;
        $rootScope.getPrecision = function() {
          return 3;
        };
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    My number is {{ pi | number: getPrecision() }}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it is working just fine. I was almost there but couldn't find the exact way, thanks a lot :)